# I am trying to display the top -k popular movies based on rtAudienceScore where k is the limit that would be set by the user to find top k movies

Tags: java, mysql-workbench

This is the error i am getting : 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Limit  = 'parameter'' at line 1

```
 System.out.println("Connecting to database.");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

        System.out.println("Creating table in database");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        System.out.println("The Top Popular Movies");
        System.out.println("Please Enter top-k number to view top movies that you want to see" );
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int parameter = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println(parameter);

        String sql = "SELECT title, year, rtAudienceScore, rtPictureURL, imdbPictureURL FROM movies ORDER BY rtAudienceScore DESC WHERE Limit  = parameter ";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
                while(rs.next()) {
                               String title1 = rs.getString("title");
                               String year = rs.getString("year");
                               String rtAud = rs.getString("rtAudienceScore");
                               String rtPic = rs.getString("rtPictureURL");
                               String idmb = rs.getString("imdbPictureURL");
                               System.out.print("title:" + title1);
                               System.out.print(", year:" + year);
                               System.out.print(", rtAud: " + rtAud);
                               System.out.print(", rtPic: " + rtPic);
                               System.out.print(", idmb:" + idmb);
                           }
                }

    catch (SQLException e){
        System.out.print(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: `LIMIT` is a ***reserved word*** in MySQL.

Comment: Okay, but is there a way i can set the limit to parameter or by user input instead of putting in and actual integer like 5 or 10?

Comment: Use [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)